# PHP constants - const vs define vs static

Tags: static, constants, php-5.5

Problems:

1. `const` variables cannot be concated (but we can achieve this with constant `define`).
2. `define` slows on runtime - especially when you have a **long** list of defines.

Static - the solution?

define,

```
define('prefix','hello');
define('suffix','world');
define('greeting',prefix.' '.suffix);
```

static,

```
class greeting 
{
    static public $prefix = 'hello';
    static public $suffix = 'world';
    static public $concat = 'default';

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$concat = self::$prefix.' '.self::$suffix;
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. So which one is faster then? How can I test them?
2. Why do I have to make an instance of `greeting` before I can change the **default** value of `$concat` (see below)?

`greeting` Usage:

```
var_dump(greeting::$concat);  // default

new greeting(); // I don't even need to store it in a variable like $object = new greeting();
var_dump(greeting::$concat); // hello world
```

That is strange. How can I not to make an instance of `greeting` but still can get the correct result?

Any ideas what I can do to make this better?

Answer (score 3):

static properties are still mutable! What you want are class constants:

```php
<?php
class greeting
{
    const prefix = 'hello';
    const suffix = 'world';
}

echo greeting::prefix, ' ', greeting::suffix ; 
# Yields: Hello world
```

If you have a lot of constants, you might want to use serialize() to write a cache file and in your code unserialize(). Depending on your use case, the file open + unserialize() might be faster than the PHP runner.

Comment: thanks I know that but I need something shorter. `greeting::saysomething`

Comment: `const` only accepts scalar data unlike `define()` which evaluates the expression.